# Combo box setValue JavaFX

Tags: java, combobox, javafx, fxml

I have a combo box and I set the default value for this combo box at the initialisation of the node. However, once there is some data retrieved from a database I want to update this default value to something else.

```
initialise() {
businessDateComboBox.setItems(config.retrievedPositionsData().getDistinctBusinssDate()); 
businessDateComboBox.setValue(config.retrievedPositionsData().getCurrentBusinessDate().toString());
}
```

The setItems is an ObservableList and the setValue is an ObservableList to but ive converted it to string.

Now I use a separate thread to retrieve items from database.

```
public void readPositionsFromDataBase() throws Exception {
    Task<Integer> task = new Task<Integer>() {
        @Override protected Integer call() throws Exception {       
            config.positionViewPersister().readDataFromDataBase(null,null);
            return 0;
        }
    };
    Thread th = new Thread(task);
    th.setDaemon(true);
    th.start();
config.retrievedPositionsData().setCurrentBusinessDate("56")    
}
```

Once this finishes I want to update the User Interface with the latest value retrieved for default combo box value. I do this by reloading the FXML and the corresponding controller of the FXML which consists of the initialise method - currently the initialise method is run again but the user interface does not get updated with the latest value. Does anyone know why?

The default value in combo box in user interface should now be 56 as ive set it. When I print businessDateComboBox.getValue() it gives 56 it just isn't updating the User Interface.

Is there any equivalent of the swing redraw or something?

Answer (score 0):

`businessDateComboBox.setValue` is meant for the edit component of an editable `ComboBox`. I guess yours is not, so the right way to go should via the `SelectionModel`:

```
businessDateComboBox.getSelectionModel().select(...)
```

Comment: I don't have the setSelectedItem option under getSelectionModel. However I used selectLast but this didn't quite update the UI as well?

Comment: Sorry, meant `select()`. Edited the answer. If both don`t work, somethin other is not workin in your code. For example: Reloading the whole GUI via FXML seems rather unnecessary..

Comment: `setValue(...)` or `select(...)` will only work if the value you pass in is an element of the list (which it should be for this to make any sense anyway). This looks unlikely with the code you provided; if the list is a list of `String`s, then `toString()` is redundant. What is the type of the `ComboBox` and the `ObservableList` you are providing?

Comment: James_D: It is a list of strings but setValue only accepts a String not a list. Hence the conversation. Maybe I will pass in a similar value to what is on the list? Does the value have to match or does the type have to match?

Comment: If you call `select(xyz)`, the object `xyz` has to be exactly the same (as `equals()`) as in the backing list of the `ComboBox`.

Comment: Yes I said selectLast so that should not be a problem?

Comment: `selectLast()` will select the last element of the list.

Comment: But it does not select the last element. I mean it selects the last element when the fxml first loads. and after a data update of the underlying values for these lists it doesn't select the last date.

Comment: ... if you update the data of `ComboBox` the selection will be cleared.

Comment: Right I see - so how exactly do I handle that then? to show the new selection after a data update of the combo box values.

Comment: Remember the selection before and restore it after the update?